# The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (Unable to start terminal process: CreateProcess failed)

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, salesforce-communities

I have tried all the solution suggested to open terminal but it always shown that terminal process failed to launch  and ***CreateProcess*** failed.
I also reinstall Visual Code but it shows same error. Please suggest me solution.